# What methods to replace simple special characters with Unicode characters nicely and quickly?

Tags: unicode

I can use AutoHotKey to replace some simple math characters to Unicode characters. For example, `:*:L2::L²` will replace `L2` to `L²` automatically. But then I have to define another `:*:S2::S²` just to write `S²`. Even a generic `:*:^2::²` is not ultimate since there are not only numbers, but letters, not only superscripts, but overscripts. In short, I want to have a systematic method to use [all available special characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts) at once.

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: How is this related with TeX/LaTeX? I think you should ask on Super User or another StackExchange site.

Comment: Why not just use a IME?